# How to count the members returned by ALL

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a very simple attempt at a `DAX` measure:

```
CountAllCustomers = COUNTA( ALL( play[customer] ) )
```

What exactly does this part of the expression `ALL( play[customer] )` return?
I assumed it returns a single column table and is therefore a valid argument for `COUNTA` - but it is not - why not?

How do I amend to keep `ALL` and count what is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression does not work, because [COUNTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/counta-function-dax) expects a column reference (think column name), while [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) returns a table (table instance is not table reference, thus it's not valid parameter for COUNTA).

Maybe [COUNTROWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countrows-function-dax) is what you need in your case:

```
CountAllCustomers = COUNTROWS(ALL(play[customer]))
```